# Store a variable-sized list of strings in some column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I am a newbie in sql and mysql (in fact, I use mariadb implementation). I need to store a variable-sized list of strings in some column. Example: it may take the value

`'one'` or `['one', 'two']`, or `['one', 'two', 'three']` just like an array type in python or other high level languages.

What kind of data-type (if such exists) can I use?

Comment: Have you tried Googling this? These answers should help (the bottom line, though, is you're best using another table):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360739/how-to-store-array-or-multiple-values-in-one-column
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341149/store-array-of-numbers-in-database-field

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a data-type to do what you are wanting to do directly. Rather you would store your "variable-sized list of strings" in another table, and use a column from your existing table to refer to that other table.  This is called a join.

For example, if you have a table structured like so...

```
TABLE: Shelf
id : int
location : varchar(50)
books : int
```

And another table

```
TABLE: Books
bookId: int
Title: varchar(80)
```

Then you could find all the books at location x with the following query...

```
SELECT s.location, b.title FROM Shelf s
INNER JOIN Books b on s.books = b.bookId
WHERE s.location = 'x'
ORDER BY b.title;
```

There is a far better explanation of this at  https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Thank you! However, I am not sure this is what I have to do. That means I should create a table with some unique name that contains row of CHAR entries. Isn't that a lot of manual work? And How should access a table with a variable name (the name listed in the base table)?

Comment: A lot of manual work is a subjective term. For a database such as MySql, joins to other tables are how you handle multivalue data.  If you really need to collapse everything into one column, you'll need to find a different type of database. Multivalue databases that .come to mind are U2 (unidata) or OpenQm, Here are some references http://www.openqm-zumasys.com/openqm/what-is-multivalue/ and http://nosql-database.org/